# F# casting type from query expression

Tags: f#

I have a query expression of the form:

```
let result = query { for row in context.Table do
                     where (row.id = 111111)
                     select (row.col1,row.col2,row.col3) }
```

Result returns a value of type IQueryable<Nullable<float>*Nullable<float>*Nullable<float>>. I want it to return seq<float>*seq<float>*seq<float>.

I can try altering it like so:

```
let result :seq<float>*seq<float>*seq<float> = query { for row in context.Table do
                                               where (row.id = 111111)
                                               select (row.col1,row.col2,row.col3) }
                     |> Seq.cast
```

But I get:

Type mismatch. Expecting a IQueryable<Nullable<float> * Nullable<float> * Nullable<float>> -> seq<float> * seq<float> * seq<float>
but given a IQueryable<Nullable<float> * Nullable<float> * Nullable<float>> -> seq<'a>
The type 'seq<float> * seq<float> * seq<float>' does not match the type 'seq<'a>'

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here's what I am trying to do, it sounds like my question may give me a usable answer but not the best way to do what I want. This code is ugly but works:

```
let col1 : seq<float> = query { for row in context.Table do
                                 where (row.id = 111111)
                                 select row.col1 }
                         |> Seq.cast 

let col2 : seq<float> = query { for row in context.Table do
                                 where (row.id = 111111)
                                 select row.col2 }
                         |> Seq.cast

let model = MathNet.Numerics.Interpolation.CubicSpline.InterpolateAkima(col1,col2)
```

If I don't cast to float, InterpolateAkima won't work because it doesn't accept type Nullable. I don't want to have to do a query for each column on its own, though. My eventual goal is to have a function where I can pass in any value of row.id and get the model for col1,col2 then col1,col3 and so on.

Comment: Why do you want `seq<float>*seq<float>*seq<float>`? What do you expect it to be?

Comment: @MarkSeemann, I am passing the values out of the table to a function that doesn't accept nullables. If I pull one column at a time, I can use |> Seq.cast to convert to a float. I wanted to be able to pull all columns at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts in this question:

- Transforming a `seq<a * b * c>` into `seq<a> * seq<b> * seq<c>`: `List.unzip3` and `Array.unzip3` do exactly that.
- Getting rid of the Nullable: it depends on what you want to happen when a value is null.

  - If you want to return 0 for null values:

    ```
    let col1, col2, col3 =
        query { for row in context.Table do
                where (row.id = 111111)
                let col1 = if row.col1.HasValue then row.col1.Value else 0.
                let col2 = if row.col2.HasValue then row.col2.Value else 0.
                let col3 = if row.col3.HasValue then row.col3.Value else 0.
                select (col1, col2, col3) }
        |> Array.ofSeq
        |> Array.unzip3
    ```
  - If you want to ignore rows where there is a null:

    ```
    let col1, col2, col3 =
        query { for row in context.Table do
                where (row.id = 111111 && row.col1.HasValue && row.col2.HasValue && row.col3.HasValue)
                select (row.col1.Value, row.col2.Value, row.col3.Value) }
        |> Array.ofSeq
        |> Array.unzip3
    ```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is there a way to scale this up to more than three columns? Array.unzip3 only takes three inputs, and there isn't a higher unzip available that I can find.

Comment: There are no built-in functions for unzipping tuples bigger than 3 indeed, but you can always implement it yourself; the code will look like @Nikon the Third's `seqTuple`.

Answer (score 1):

I, like Mark, am wondering what you are trying to accomplish with this, but nevertheless, here is one way how you could do it:

```
open System
open System.Linq

// Helpers to recreate your circumstances.
type Context = { id : Int32; col1 : Nullable<Double>; col2 : Nullable<Double>; col3 : Nullable<Double>}
let context = Unchecked.defaultof<IQueryable<Context>>


let result = query { for row in context do
                     where (row.id = 111111)
                     select (row.col1,row.col2,row.col3) }


let seqTuple =
    result
    |> Seq.fold (fun (col1s, col2s, col3s) (col1, col2, col3) ->
        (if col1.HasValue then col1.Value :: col1s else col1s),
        (if col2.HasValue then col2.Value :: col2s else col2s),
        (if col3.HasValue then col3.Value :: col3s else col3s)
    ) ([], [], [])
    |> fun (col1s, col2s, col3s) ->
        List.rev col1s,
        List.rev col2s,
        List.rev col3s
```